# PHP if statement: Zero vs 'empty'

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields, zero

I'm creating a WordPress website using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I have a set of fields for tennis score results. In the template, I'm showing these fields like this:

```
<?php if(get_field('my_field')) : ?>
   <?php echo get_field('my_field'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that some scores are zero, so they're not showing up. I understand that this is because 0 basically equals null, so the statement is false.

One solution I found and tried was this:

```
<?php if(get_field('my_field') !== false) : ?>
   <?php echo get_field('my_field'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this means that empty fields now show up too, which is not desirable since there are a lot of fields that are intended to be hidden if empty.

So, my question is, is there a way to phrase an if statement that allows for zeros, while still returning false if the field is empty? Please note that some scores aren't purely numeric, with values like '6(1)'.

Comment: this is not true:  `0 basically equals null,` 0 is int. Or string 0. Numeric type. Do var_dump on it to see  what you get in it.

Comment: Make a list of all possible values you may get and their type. Express what values should be truthy and which falsey. Look at the PHP comparison rules whether any match your requirement.

Comment: If you only want to exclude empty strings, then add the corresponding test inside the if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check for empty strings you have to explicitly check them in your if condition.

```
<?php if(get_field('my_field') !== '') : ?>
   <?php echo get_field('my_field'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The reason is *0*, *null*, *empty string*, *empty array* all evaluate to (*but are not exactly*) false, in case of a boolean check.

Comment: Thanks very much. This works well for my purposes.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help!